# How to iterate over variable in param using JSF EL expression

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, el

I have a PrimeFaces `<p:dataGrid>` component that contains a variable number of panels.  Each panel contains a number of derived components. I have a delete button contained inside each of these panels to allow for deletion. I also have an add button outside of the dataGrid.  Instead of using `immediate="true"` on the buttons, I figured out how to set the required attribute of each component in each panel.

For instance:

```
required="#{empty param['vehicleGrid:0:btnDelete'] and empty param['btnAdd']}".
```

For every delete button in the dataGrid and the add button, ignore component validation.

This works if there is a panel inside of the dataGrid, but it only references the first one.  I need to dynamically check every panel. Maybe instead of looking at it from the markup page, maybe I need to look at it in Java terms since param is a `Map<String, String>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the delete button component to the view and use [`UIComponent#getClientId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId%28%29) instead.

```
<h:inputText ... required="#{empty param[deleteButton.clientId]}" />
...
<h:commandButton binding="#{deleteButton}" ... />
```

This way the proper client ID will be looked up in the parameter map and there's then no need to iterate over the parameter map.

Comment: Ok that almost worked!  I can see that the panel the delete button is in bypasses validation in that panel, but how do I ignore all panels?  Let's say I add 3 empty panels and then try to delete the last panel.  It won't do it since the validation of the first two panels are triggered.  In this case, a delete button in one panel will ignore validations in all panels.

Comment: So, you're using PrimeFaces command button? Set `process="@this"` instead of (default) `process="@form"`. Oh wait... this way you don't need that `required` condition altogether and you can just stick to `required="this"` :)

Comment: Hmm I originally did that until I ran into issues with data between the view and the backing bean.  For example, I have 3 vehicles and each vehicle has a year attribute.  I enter 2008, 2010, and 2012 respectively.  Then I delete the first vehicle.  Instead of getting 2010 and 2012, I see 2008 and 2012.  The backing list has the correct data but for some reason the prior data displayed.  Worse, if I added a new vehicle or updated, that "ghost" data just overlayed the backing list.  It drove me crazy until another poster recommended simplifying the code a bit.

Comment: Just for kicks I added back the process="@this" and even added the p:ajax update="@this" and so far all is good.  3 days ago this didn't work as I manually refreshed the screen, the values would change.  The ajax tag was needed so that the button clicks didn't blank out the values of any new values.